# Wordpress Tablesorter Zebra stripe plug-in for beginner

Tags: wordpress, tablesorter

I'm trying to add the `zebra-stripe` plugin to a `wordpress` page.

I am not sure where to place the following code in order to make the zebra striping work.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thank you!

```
$(function() {

  // call the tablesorter plugin
  $("table").tablesorter({
    theme: 'blue',
    // initialize zebra striping of the table
    widgets: ["zebra"],
    // change the default striping class names
    // updated in v2.1 to use widgetOptions.zebra = ["even", "odd"]
    // widgetZebra: { css: [ "normal-row", "alt-row" ] } still works
    widgetOptions : {
      zebra : [ "normal-row", "alt-row" ]
    }
  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the [Wordpress table-sorter plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/table-sorter/) is using the original tablesorter (v2.0.5) so the `theme` and `widgetOptions` settings do not do anything.

If you're not using that plugin, but you are using my [fork of tablesorter](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/), then you need to load the `/css/theme.blue.css` file and *not* change the default zebra class names:

```
$(function() {
  $("table").tablesorter({
    theme: 'blue',
    widgets: ["zebra"]
  });
});
```

If you are using the original tablesorter without the Wordpress plugin, use the same code above, except for the `theme` setting; the blue style that needs to be loaded will be in the following location `/themes/blue/style.css`.